# Comparing categorical data with reference data

Tags: regression, correlation, categorical-data

I have an idea for an analysis I would be interesting in performing for my PhD project, but I'm a bit unsure of how the underlying statistics would work. I have some minor experience with statistics, but it's more of a general idea of broad concepts rather than detailed information, and so I come here to ask for some help.

What I want to do is, essentially, somehow compare categorical data to a reference, and see how close the data is to the reference. The data and reference is several hundreds of categorical points, and the comparison would be (I imagine) somehow comparing each point in the data to the point in the reference, see if they match, and get some kind of summarized comparison value for all the points. For conceptual visualization:

```
Reference        A    G    G    H    C    D   ...
Data             A    G    C    H    C    B   ...
```

The `Data` here differs twice from the `Reference`, which would then detract from it's comparative score/correlation/whatever you call it. A perfect score would be that all the points are exactly the same in the data and reference (which would almost never be the case for my data).

( An assumption is that each point is independent from each other. This would be true for most of my data, and an acceptable assumption in the rest of the cases - but is it possible to also do whatever statistics I should do if the points were dependent on each other in some manner? )

What am I looking for here? I did some googling on terms I thought might be applicable, but I didn't really find anything. Perhaps I just don't know what I'm looking for, hence this thread. Is it some kind of regression analysis I need? If so, how does that work for binary categorical TRUE/FALSE matches like these? If not, what else do I need?

Comment: Are you simply trying to assess how different your data is from the reference? How many rows of data will you have - just 1, or many? Does it matter where differences occur/what the difference is or just that a difference has occurred?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do; quantifying the difference from the reference. I would only have one row at a time (data), but several thousand columns (points); there would be a different References to various Data sets. I would prefer to get some kind of list with the results of where the differences are situated, if possible, but the quantification itself is the most important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I might suggest is using the Hamming distance. This metric takes each pair of corresponding elements in the data and reference group and records a $1$ if they are different and $0$ if they are the same and, once the $0$s and $1$s have been calculated for each pair, you sum up the numbers to get a measure of how different the two strings are.

I would calculate the Hamming distance for each pair of data/reference strings that you have.  You then have a set of data $X$ where $X_i=k_i$ and $k_i=$ the number of differences between data string $i$ and reference string $i$.  With your data $X$, you can estimate the distribution to see how many differences there are on average (i.e. the mean of $X$) and how much variation there is in these differences (i.e. the standard deviation of $X$).  There are perhaps better measures if your data set is skewed, but this might help you to get an idea of how much of a difference between the reference and data strings you should expect to see.